# Problema Adapter

Tags: android-studio, realm, adapter

Tengo un problema en en mi `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

Mi error es el siguiente

> java.lang.NullPointerException on: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.piipe.bienestapp.Modelos.usuario.getNombre()' on a null object reference

Yo pienso que que el problema esta al momento asignar asignar el modelo usuario al modelo mSocial lo asigna como nullo. Adjunto código por si me pueden ayudar. Gracias

**Social.java**

```
public class Social extends Fragment {

private List<mSocial> lSocial;
private RealmResults<mSocial> socialResult;

private RecyclerView socialRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter socialAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private Realm mRealm;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeSocial;


public Social() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_social, container, false);

        mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        socialResult = mRealm.where(mSocial.class).findAll();

        if (socialResult.size() == 0){
            if (MyUtilities.verificaConexion(getContext())){
                GetAlluser();
                GetAllPost();
            }
        }

        swipeSocial = v.findViewById(R.id.swipePost);
        lSocial = this.getAllPostFalso();

        socialRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.listPost);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        socialAdapter = new socialAdapter(socialResult, R.layout.item_list_social, new socialAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnItemClick(mSocial social, int position) {

            }
        });

        socialRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
       socialRecyclerView.setAdapter(socialAdapter);

        swipeSocial.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                if (MyUtilities.verificaConexion(getActivity())){
                    GetAlluser();
                    GetAllPost();

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Esta acción necesita conexión a internet, comprueba tu conexión", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    onItemsLoadComplete();
                }
            }
        });

    return v;
}

private RealmResults<usuario> listarUusuarios() {
    RealmResults<usuario> list = mRealm.where(usuario.class).findAll();
    return list;
}

private void GetAlluser() {
    if (MyUtilities.verificaConexion(getContext())) {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        String URL = "http://www.nodclous.com/bienestapp/apiRcv/GetInfoAllUserBienestApp";

        JsonObjectRequest jsonReque = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                              try {
                            String status = response.getString("status");

                            JSONArray mensaje = response.getJSONArray("mensaje");

                            if (status.equals("success")) {
                                getAllNamesJson(mensaje);

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error no se puedo realizar la consulta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // VolleyLog.d("JSONPost", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        queue.add(jsonReque);
    }
}

private ArrayList<usuario> getAllNames() {

    return new ArrayList<usuario>() {
        {
            add(new usuario(111111111, "nombre1","apellido1",0,"Masculino","Estudiante","1234","none"));
            add(new usuario(111111111, "nombre2","apellido2",0,"Masculino","Estudiante","1234","none"));
            add(new usuario(111111111, "nombre3","apellido3",0,"Masculino","Estudiante","1234","none"));
            add(new usuario(111111111, "nombre4","apellido4",0,"Masculino","Estudiante","1234","none"));
            add(new usuario(111111111, "nombre5","apellido5",0,"Masculino","Estudiante","1234","none"));
            add(new usuario(111111111, "nombre6","apellido6",0,"Masculino","Estudiante","1234","none"));
            add(new usuario(111111111, "nombre7","apellido7",0,"Masculino","Estudiante","1234","none"));
            add(new usuario(111111111, "nombre8","apellido8",0,"Masculino","Estudiante","1234","none"));
            add(new usuario(111111111, "nombre9","apellido9",0,"Masculino","Estudiante","1234","none"));
            add(new usuario(111111111, "nombre10","apellido10",0,"Masculino","Estudiante","1234","none"));


        }
    };
}

private ArrayList<mSocial> getAllPostFalso() {

    return new ArrayList<mSocial>() {
        {
            add(new mSocial(999999999, "titulo1","body1",null,0,0,0,null,"none"));
            add(new mSocial(999999999, "titulo2","body2",null,0,0,0,null,"none"));

        }
    };
}

private void getAllNamesJson(JSONArray mensaje) {

  /* mRealm.beginTransaction();
    mRealm.delete(usuario.class);
    mRealm.commitTransaction();*/

    try {

        if (mensaje.length() > 0) {

            for (int i = 0; i < mensaje.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = mensaje.getJSONObject(i);

                int rut = jsonObject.getInt("rutUsuario");
                String nombre = jsonObject.getString("nombreUsuario");
                String apellido = jsonObject.getString("apellidoUsuario");
                int edad = jsonObject.getInt("edadUsuario");
                String sexo = jsonObject.getString("sexoUsuario");
                String ocupacion = jsonObject.getString("ocupacionUsuario");
                String password = jsonObject.getString("passwordUsuario");
                String ruta = jsonObject.getString("rutaImagen");
                String img = jsonObject.getString("imgBase64");
                Log.d("Carga Usuario",nombre);
                usuario usuarioJson = new usuario(rut, nombre,apellido,edad,sexo,ocupacion,password,img);
                mRealm.beginTransaction();
                mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(usuarioJson);
                mRealm.commitTransaction();
            }

        }

        mRealm.close();
       //onItemsLoadComplete();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void onItemsLoadComplete() {
    // Update the adapter and notify data set changed
    // ...

    // Stop refresh animation
    swipeSocial.setRefreshing(false);
}

private void imprimirUsuarios(){
    RealmResults<usuario> us= mRealm.where(usuario.class).findAll();

    for (int i = 0; i< us.size();i++){
        Log.d("Usuario",us.get(i).getNombre());
    }
}

private void imprimirSocial(){
    RealmResults<mSocial> us= mRealm.where(mSocial.class).findAll();

    for (int i = 0; i< us.size();i++){
        Log.d("TituloPost",us.get(i).getTituloPost());
    }
}

private void GetAllPost() {
    if (MyUtilities.verificaConexion(getContext())) {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        String URL = "http://www.nodclous.com/bienestapp/apiRcv/GetSocial";

        JsonObjectRequest jsonReque = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            String status = response.getString("status");

                            JSONArray mensaje = response.getJSONArray("mensaje");


                            if (status.equals("success")) {
                                getAllPostJson(mensaje);

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error no se puedo realizar la consulta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // VolleyLog.d("JSONPost", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        queue.add(jsonReque);
    }
}

private void getAllPostJson(JSONArray mensaje) {
    //lSocial.clear();
   /* mRealm.beginTransaction();
    mRealm.delete(mSocial.class);
    mRealm.commitTransaction();*/

    try {

        if (mensaje.length() > 0) {

            for (int i = 0; i < mensaje.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = mensaje.getJSONObject(i);

                int rut = jsonObject.getInt("rutUsuario_fk");
                int idPost = jsonObject.getInt("idPublicacion");
                String titulo = jsonObject.getString("tituloPublicacion");
                String body = jsonObject.getString("bodyPublicacion");
                int reaccion1 = jsonObject.getInt("reaccion1");
                int reaccion2 = jsonObject.getInt("reaccion2");
                int reaccion3 = jsonObject.getInt("reaccion3");
                int idMeta_fk = jsonObject.getInt("idMeta_fk");
                String fechaPost = jsonObject.getString("fechaPost");
                Log.d("TituloPost","rutUsuario"+rut);
                mMeta metaPost = mRealm.where(mMeta.class).equalTo("idMeta",idMeta_fk).findFirst();
                usuario usuarioPost = mRealm.where(usuario.class).equalTo("rut",rut).findFirst();
           /*     Log.d("TituloPost","rutUsuario2 "+ usuarioPost.getNombre());
                Log.d("IMAGEN","IMAGEN "+ usuarioPost.getImagePerfil());*/

                lSocial.add(new mSocial(idPost, titulo,body,usuarioPost,reaccion1,reaccion2,reaccion3,metaPost,MyUtilities.CambiaFecha2(fechaPost)));

            }

        }
        mRealm.beginTransaction();
        mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(lSocial);
        mRealm.commitTransaction();
        mRealm.close();
        socialRecyclerView.setAdapter(socialAdapter);
        socialAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        onItemsLoadComplete();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

**socialAdapter.java**

```
public class socialAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<socialAdapter.ViewHolder>{


private List<mSocial> arrayList;
private int resource;

private OnItemClickListener itemClickListener;



public socialAdapter(List<mSocial> arrayList, int resource, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.itemClickListener = listener;
}

public void updateList(final ArrayList<mSocial> data) {
    arrayList = data;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(resource, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(arrayList.get(position),itemClickListener);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    TextView nombreSocial;
    TextView nameMetaSocial;
    TextView descriptionMetaSocial;
    TextView fechaSocial;
    CircleImageView imagenPerfil;
    TextView confiaText;
    IconButton confiaIcon;
    private Context context;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.nombreSocial = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombreSocial);
        this.nameMetaSocial = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombreMetaSocial);
        this.descriptionMetaSocial = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descripcionMetaSocial);
        this.imagenPerfil = itemView.findViewById(R.id.circleFotoSocial);
        this.confiaText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.badge_textView);
        this.confiaIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.badge_icon_button);
        this.context = itemView.getContext();
        this.fechaSocial = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fechaSocial);
    }

    public void bind(final mSocial social, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
        Log.d("DENTRO ADAPTER",social.getTituloPost());
        Log.d("DENTRO ADAPTER",social.getDatosUser().getNombre());

        if(!social.getDatosUser().getImagePerfil().equals("none")){
            String previouslyEncodedImage = social.getDatosUser().getImagePerfil();
            if (!previouslyEncodedImage.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                byte[] b = Base64.decode(previouslyEncodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
                imagenPerfil.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
        }else {

            imagenPerfil.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_contacto_1);
        }


        nombreSocial.setText(social.getDatosUser().getNombre()+" "+social.getDatosUser().getApellido());
        nameMetaSocial.setText(social.getTituloPost());
        descriptionMetaSocial.setText(social.getBodyPost());
        fechaSocial.setText(social.getFechaPost());
        confiaIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int cont = Integer.parseInt(confiaText.getText().toString());
                cont = cont+1;
                confiaText.setText(String.valueOf(cont));
            }
        });
    }
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void OnItemClick(mSocial social, int position);
}}
```

Exepción completa

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.piipe.bienestapp, PID: 10724
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.piipe.bienestapp.Modelos.usuario.getNombre()' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.piipe.bienestapp.AdapterApp.socialAdapter$ViewHolder.bind(socialAdapter.java:96)
                  at com.example.piipe.bienestapp.AdapterApp.socialAdapter.onBindViewHolder(socialAdapter.java:62)
                  at com.example.piipe.bienestapp.AdapterApp.socialAdapter.onBindViewHolder(socialAdapter.java:28)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3225)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
                  at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:2263)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                  at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:547)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
                  at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onMeasure(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:622)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6427)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1632)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6427)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:739)
                  at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:91)
                  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:809)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6427)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6427)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6427)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
```

Comment: Puedes compartir la **excepción** completa? El problema esta claro. Estas intentando obtener la propiedad `nombre` de alguna instancia de `usuario` que es nulo al momento de invocar su `getter`. El problema es que hay demasiadas instancias de `usuario` como para identificarlo a simple vista. Si puedes compartir la **excepción completa**, quizás pueda analizar donde y porque llega `null` y podríamos resolver el problema.

Comment: Acabo de compartir la excepcion completa, estare atento a tu ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yo pienso que que el problema esta al momento asignar asignar el
>   modelo usuario al modelo mSocial lo asigna como nullo.

Exactamente ese es el problema si `mSocial` tiene valor null , al tratar de obtener en tu `Adapter` el valor por medio de `getNombre()` lo realiza en una instancia con valor null.

En este caso me llama la atención que no marca error en :

```
social.getTituloPost()
```

pero si en :

```
social.getDatosUser().getNombre()
```

en esta parte del código:

```
 public void bind(final mSocial social, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
        Log.d("DENTRO ADAPTER",social.getTituloPost());
        Log.d("DENTRO ADAPTER",social.getDatosUser().getNombre());

        if(!social.getDatosUser().getImagePerfil().equals("none")){
            String previouslyEncodedImage = social.getDatosUser().getImagePerfil();
            if (!previouslyEncodedImage.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                byte[] b = Base64.decode(previouslyEncodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
                imagenPerfil.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
        }else {

            imagenPerfil.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_contacto_1);
        }


        nombreSocial.setText(social.getDatosUser().getNombre()+" "+social.getDatosUser().getApellido());
 ...
```

Debes asegurarte que el Post obtenga correctamente los datos y en este caso me parece que no es necesario llamar a `getDatosUser()` , simplemente:

```
//social.getDatosUser().getNombre()
social.getNombre()
```

lo mismo para obtener los demás valores.